# Anonymous edits that don't change anything

Tags: discussion, moderation, review

So I recently checked and rejected 3 reviews that literally changed nothing from an anonymous user. These edits changed nothing, improved nothing, did nothing. I know there is the community bot, but that should have happened automatically. I'm curious why this was an anonymous user(it was the same user for all 3 edits)

I'm posting here wondering if anyone else has noticed this, what should we do, and is this the community bot, or an anonymous user trying to game the system?

By game the system I mean they post the edits, hope enough get accepted, and then register an account to gain all of the reputation and merge it with an existing user.

Has this happened before or is this just some anomaly?

Comment: Just be careful of these as sometimes reviewers only take note of the post and not the tags. Edits to the tags on a question can be perfectly valid and may not be as noticeable if you aren't watching them. Conversely, make sure you check for tag edits when approving an edit to the post as sometimes bad tags get slipped in with other edits.

Comment: Links to the reviews for the curious: **[1](http://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/63595)   [2](http://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/63596)   [3](http://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/63597)** They are making changes, look at the Markdown. It looks like a broken bot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sort of thing happens all the time. Enough rejects from reviewers helps prevent them doing it after a short while.

In short, no anomaly, it's very common. You, and reviewers like you help prevent it being a problem.